# android enable or disable passcode lock using shared preference

Tags: android, passwords, sharedpreferences, settings, lockscreen

I designed an passcode lock activity which requires the user to input a passcode before accessing the app.

I have a setting page which allow user to enable or disable the passcode lock, and the setting is saved in sharedpreference

How can the app:

- show the passcodelock activity upon launch or resume if the "Passcode Lock" in setting page is checked?
- not show the passcodelock activity if the "Passcode Lock" in setting page is unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple Logic 
just in Oncreate method of Your Passcode Activity get value of "Passcode Lock" from  shared preference

```
if(Passcode){
/*
* startActivity(new Intent(this,yourNextpage.class));
*
/
}
```

so you if "Passcode Lock" checked not display Passcode activity...

Hope it help for you

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate method of the launcher activity, you could check the value of shared preference.

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("passcode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String str = sp.getString("passcode","");
```

If str is set let's say 0, then you could launch PasscodeLockActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,PasscodeLockActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I guess this would solve the problem.